# How to implement Navigator.replace using NavigationStateUtils in React Native + Redux?

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, reactjs

In my `navReducer.js`, have the following that handles .pop and .push. But following the same guidelines, using `NavigationStateUtils`, how can I implement .replace where it replaces the current scene with the new route? Much like the `Navigator.replace`.

```
import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native'

const {
  StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils
} = NavigationExperimental

function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

   default:
     return state

  }
}

export default navigationState
```

Comment: i'm also interested by answer

Comment: @Fantasim Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

but it's already there at NavigationStateUtils?

```
/**
 * Replace a route by a key.
 * Note that this moves the index to the positon to where the new route in the
 * stack is at.
 */
function replaceAt(
  state: NavigationState,
  key: string,
  route: NavigationRoute,
): NavigationState {
  const index = indexOf(state, key);
  return replaceAtIndex(state, index, route);
}

/**
 * Replace a route by a index.
 * Note that this moves the index to the positon to where the new route in the
 * stack is at.
 */
function replaceAtIndex(
  state: NavigationState,
  index: number,
  route: NavigationRoute,
): NavigationState {
  invariant(
    !!state.routes[index],
    'invalid index %s for replacing route %s',
    index,
    route.key,
  );

  if (state.routes[index] === route) {
    return state;
  }

  const routes = state.routes.slice();
  routes[index] = route;

  return {
    ...state,
    index,
    routes,
  };
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not quiet understanding. Before I accept the answer and upvote, how would I integrate into my navReducer and could you show a revised example? I am trying to follow the same format as how `PUSH_ROUTE` and `POP_ROUTE` are set up.

Comment: I just setup a sample project, mainly about NavigationExperimental: https://github.com/Sunshow/react-native-redux-starter-kit

Answer (score -1):

Check out "navigationStateUtils.jumpTo" method:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js

It make a redirect to route by given route key. **Important note**: You will have to be aware of pushing same route keys again via "navigationStateUtils.push" after this operation.

Here`s inner structure of method:

```
jumpTo(state: NavigationState, key: string): NavigationState {
    const index = NavigationStateUtils.indexOf(state, key);
    return NavigationStateUtils.jumpToIndex(state, index);
}
```

Edited version of your code with implemented method:

```
import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native'

const {
  StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils
} = NavigationExperimental

function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

    case JUMP_TO_ROUTE:
      return NavigationStateUtils.jumpTo(action.routeKey)

   default:
     return state

  }
}

export default navigationState
```